# Audio not playing (as intended) in mobile browser (native and HowlerJS)

Tags: javascript, html, audio, howler.js

Project — http://codepen.io/abdulahhamzic/pen/ALQqGq

This is the HowlerJS code I'm using to play an audio file on document load:

```
var simonSaysSong = new Howl({
  src: ['http://czechmyjugs.com/Simon%20Says.mp3'],
  preload: true,
  loop: true
});
simonSaysSong.play();
```

Previously I used this code to play the audio using the native JavaScript method:

```
var simonSaysSong = new Audio('http://czechmyjugs.com/Simon%20Says.mp3');
simonSaysSong.play();
```

Both of these work pretty well on desktop browser, but neither ever gets to play the audio when using my Samsung Galaxy S i9000 native browser.

Another thing is that there is an audio delay on button (any of the colored divs) click. The sound effects play a few seconds after I click the button. Same here, it does work on desktop browsers whether using HowlerJS or the audio() method, whereas it doesn't on my phone's browser.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js#mobile-playback. Audio playback must first be unlocked on mobile inside a `touchedn` or `click` event.

Comment: thanks man! @JamesSimpson so, that explains why the song won't play on page load... but, what about the audio delay with the sound effects on button click? They are invoked by a click event, why is it that they don't even play half of the time?

Comment: @JamesSimpson you fixed my problem - I couldn't get Samsung Browser to play native `Audio()` because I was using `touchstart` instead of `touchend`. Many thanks <3